# Iterating over List in a Map

Tags: java, collections

What is the best way to iterate over a "de-normalized" map of collections?

For example, I have the following map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> relations;
```

In order to iterate over each key -> each value I do something like:

```
for (Entry<String,List<String>> e : relations.entries()) {
   for (String s : e.getValue()) {
       System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + s);
   }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to solve it with some decorator or so?

I'm hoping to find something like:

```
for(Entry e : Collections.getDenormalizeEntriesFromMapOfCollection(myMap)) {
   System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue());
}
```

That would give same result, just on the second situation you would have one entry for each key -> collection item.

Comment: [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) should be able to do what you want (if you can switch from `Map<K, List<V>>`). If you're only interested in the innermost values of each `List<String>`, there's also `Iterables.concat(relations.values())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at guavas `MultiMap` implementation. It already have this kind of iterator:

To transform a `Map<K, Collection<V>` to a `MultiMap<K, V>` you can use a utility method:

```
public static <K,V> Multimap<K,V> toMultiMap(Map<K,? extends Collection<V>> m) {

    LinkedListMultimap<K, V> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();

    for (Entry<K, ? extends Collection<V>> e : m.entrySet())
        multimap.putAll(e.getKey(), e.getValue());

    return multimap;
}
```

---

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

    map.put("Hello", Arrays.asList(1, 2));
    map.put("World!", Arrays.asList(3));

    Multimap<String, Integer> multimap = toMultiMap(map);

    Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = multimap.entries().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
        System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hello=1
Hello=2
World=3
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no more elegant way as the one you're using to iterate over a `Map<String, List<String>>`. But a more elegant thing to do would be to use a [Guava ListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html), which provides an `entries()` method over which you can iterate directly, without a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Eclipse's debugger does exactly that, you can check out the implementation. Otherwise you can write a helper method in an utility class for example since the Collections framework doesn't support this as far as I know.